# Finding loop invariant

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

I am really new concerning loop invariants and I am currently trying to figure out a loop invariant of an algorithm for prime numbers. I tried a lot of ideas, but I still have problems since there are two nested loops. I am also really grateful if someone have any tips regarding finding a loop invariant.
My idea is that all $i$ which are primes are set on true and all $i$ which are not primes are set on false.. but I don't think that this is the loop invariant.

```
PRIME_FILTER(n)
1  P = INIT(n) // Initialize array P[1::n] with True
2  P[1] = False
3  i = 2
4  while i * i <_ n
5     if P[i] == True
6       j = i * i
7       while j <_ n
8          P[j] = False // Not prime
9          j = j + i
10    i = i + 1
11 return P
```

Comment: One invariant *per loop*.

Comment: (If you chose *jerry* for a reason: I don't get *tam*.)

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what the algorithm does in its first few iterations:

- Mark all elements other than 1 as "potentially prime".
- Mark all multiples of 2, starting at 4, as "not prime".
- Mark all multiples of 3, starting at 9, as "not prime".
- Skip 4, since it is known to be not prime.
- Mark all multiples of 5, starting at 25, as "not prime".
- Skip 6, since it is known to be not prime.
- Mark all multiples of 7, starting at 49, as "not prime".

So it continues, until the next element is already larger than $\sqrt{n}$.

Here is how we can describe the contents of the array:

- All elements other than 1 are "potentially prime".
- All elements not divisible by 2 are "potentially prime", except for 2.
- All elements not divisible by 2,3 are "potentially prime", except for 2,3.
- All elements not divisible by 2,3,4 (equivalently, by 2,3) are "potentially prime", except for 2,3.

And so on.

Hopefully this gives you some ideas on the loop invariant.

Comment: Where does root of n come from? so can i say that a invariant could be P [i] = true for i = prim number and P[i] = false for all other numbers?

Comment: That’s too weak to prove by induction.

Comment: This explains the progress of the algorithm, but does not give any hint about the invariants.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop is a "for" loop in disguise, from `j` to `n` in steps `i`. The invariant can only express that all values in the array P from the initial value of `j` until the current value of `j` have been set to `False`. It is worth to note that the initial value of `j` is `i²`, hence all the indexes set to `False` are multiples of `i`.

The outer loop tries all increasing values of `i` from `2` on until `i²` exceeds `n`. The invariant of this loop expresses that for all `i` from `2` to the current value, the multiples of `i` such that `P[i]` is `True`, from `i²` to `n` have been struck out.

---

In fact, these invariants are not very informative, as they essentially repeat what the statements do. Things get more interesting if you establish, by a theorem, that all `P[i]` until the current `i` are `True` for primes and `False` otherwise. Hence the outer invariant can be rephrased as "the values in `P` up to `i` indicate primality of the corresponding index".